# float changing to scientific notation on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have contactid field that is a float with 11 or 12 numbers when I do a insert the numeric number that is the float changes to a scientific notation resulting in a duplicate key error. If I just run the Select query I get the result I expect. But when I do the insert I get the following error.  I've tried just about every cast convert there is and still end up with a scientific notation?

`Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'metavalues_primarykey'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.metavalues'. The duplicate key value is (4.56219e+014, 41070, 0).
The statement has been terminated.`

Any idea why?

I know having the DB design setup this way isn't the way it should be but it is what I have to work with. So please don't tell me that I need to change my design because I cannot do that not mine to make changes to design.

```
 contactid       fieldgroup metatableid Subfields parent Metavalue
 456209564532953    1004    41140              0    0   NULL
 456209592021740    1004    41130              0    0   NULL
 456210014777935    1004    41097              0    0   NULL
 456211077079073    1004    41107              0    0   NULL




INSERT INTO contactease.dbo.metavalues
        (contactid,
         fieldgroup,
         metatableid,
         subfield,
         metaflags,
         metavalue)
SELECT DISTINCT m.contactid,
            1004,
            mt.metatableid,
            0,
            0,
            NULL
FROM  interact.dbo..[INT_LST_CUSTOM_ENUM] sic
   INNER JOIN interact.dbo.INT_AUX_LST_CUSTOM c
           ON c.LST_CUSTOM_ENUM_ID = sic.LST_CUSTOM_ENUM_ID
              AND c.DIRECTORY_ID <> -4
   INNER JOIN contactease.dbo.main m
           ON m.custnum1 = c.LISTING_ID
   INNER JOIN contactease.dbo.metatable mt
           ON mt.metaname = sic.LST_CUSTOM_ENUM_NM
```

Comment: Let me see if I can say this so it makes sense.  If you select the already existing key, how does it compare to the one you're trying to insert cast as a float?

Comment: Remember that float (and real) are approximations in SQL Server, I'm not really sure what would happen if you jam huge numbers with no decimal places into a float.

Comment: M.contactid is the float datatype the value in the column is at the top of the example so when I do the select the value comes back as  456209564532953 but when I do an insert based off of the  select query the  456209564532953 is trying to insert as 4.5621E+14
just like if I were to import it into Excel??? Hope that makes since

Comment: I'd suspect you're getting hit by a rounding "error".  Sadly enough, no clue what you can do about it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the scientific notation is there only for the sake of displaying the error message. The value being inserted is actually the value returned by `select`. The only reason it would happen otherwise would be for the source and targer fields to be of (slightly) different datatypes which would trigger an implicit typecast/rounding. What really bothers me is the conflict occuring on a composite PK. Even if `metatableid` conflicted, where does the `41070` value come from?

Comment: The metatableid is a primary key from another table that houses the field names in our db. The metavalues table hows the value that is in that field and the contacts contact id where the data belongs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Float` is an `approximate number data type` which means it will not always show the exact number, The worst Data Type you can have on your Primary Key Column, If you have large numbers in you Primary Key you should Use `BIGINT` which is a `Exact number data type`.
Since float does not represent the exact value you might have two different values but float might consider them to be almost/appoxi same values and you get duplicate PRIMARY KEY constraint error.
**My Suggestion**
Change data types of your columns OR Add another column to use as a Primary Key.
 Preferably use INT and if you have more then 2,147,483,647 records in you table then you can use BIGINT. Honestly speaking if you ever get anywhere near this limit of INT you should consider Table Partitioning.

Comment: Agree with you, but only small remark - use BIGINT if your primary key value can exceed 2 147 483 (he can have some number which is not consequetive)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I wish that was already the case. we  are in the process of redesigning db it was very poorly designed to begin with but doesn't really help me right now.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov you forgot a few digits. A regular `int` can go up to (2,147,483,647. That's 2 billion and change. You'll need to have a whole lot of rows to justify `bigint`.

Comment: Correct, not copied whole set.

Answer (score 0):

What are the data types of the contactid column in metavalues and main, do both columns have the same datatype?

I vaguely remember having a similar issue years ago that was due to the default collation on two different servers and I believe I got around the issue by converting a numeric value to a varchar and then back for the insert. I am not sure that this will help you at all but it might give you something to try anyway.

I do agree with @Muhammed Ali though, if your tables are using a float for a primary key id column that is not good. and int or a numeric should be used.